# Diagram Bar Size changing Automatically

Tags: reporting-services, size, report, diagram

I am currently working on an SSRS Report where I display multiple diagrams,
now some of the diagrams are gonna have values in all or multiple categories, and some (see image) are only gonna have values in one category.
The problem I am having is that the diagrams with values in a single category only are HUGE as opposed to some standard size (which I consider the bars in the left side of the image to be)

Question: Is there a way to change this, or is there just nothing I can do ?

Thanks for all of your help in advance

[image: Diagram - Bar Size]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select your columns and in the Properties pane go to General > CustomAttributes.  Then either set the `PointWidth` to something less than the default of 0.8, or set the `MaxPixelPointWidth` which will set a static max width in pixels.

`PointWidth` uses relative sizing based on the number of columns and size of the chart, so for charts that have a dynamic number of columns this may be the better option.